# How to present static file results that are generated at different time to client in play 2?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am writing a web service using play 2.0 in scala.

After getting client's configuration parameters, then the web service will take a while to generate some files. (Note: some files can be short, some other files can take long).

I figured out how to get client's configurations and trigger my computation,

now I need to present the generated files to client side at the end of the session.

So questions are:

- How to present the files to client?

I'm thinking about returning a static folder link to client, so that they can go into the folder to 
see further what files are there, and so when clicking on the files, the details of the files can be shown, either jpg or text.

But how?

- How to not to block client during the generation of the files?

For example, client can still click on the files that are available at that moment. 
Then here comes the third question:

- How to let the client side know that the long-time computation file is available and listed in the folder?

I'm pretty new to web application, thanks for any suggestion, advice, or little examples are greatly appreciated too!

Comment: The generated files are store on filesystem? Do you have a webapp to show these files?

Comment: @MaFo Yes, generated files are stored on filesystem. and I don't have a separate webapp to show these files, but currently I have worked through some examples to present the static links to client and javascript to periodically pull the file existence to present available links.   Not yet resolved the problem about nonblocking part .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a web interface to show the created files to your clients and create a background job to for the long computation process. You can create a wait page where a javascript check if the file is created.

Comment: Cool! I am marching forward to the step of  `create a background job to for the long computation process`.